# AngularJS - $rootScope property value undefined in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently creating a new property in $rootScope and setting its value in one module.

```
$rootScope.test = 123;
```

I am then trying to reference this value later in a service function.

```
.factory("testFactory", function ($location, $http, $rootScope) {
    /* .... */
    return {
        testFunction : function(){
            console.log($rootScope);
            console.log($rootScope.test);
        },
        /* .... */
```

When I view the console output in Chrome, I can see that the value of test is being set properly in the $rootScope object, but I am unable to reference using the $rootScope.test syntax.  $rooScope.test simply returns undefined.

Is there any reason that you can't reference property values of $rootScope in services?  Or am I attempting to retrieve this value improperly?

---

**UPDATE** -
I have created a Plunker that demonstrates the issue that I am running into.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ePEiYh

Comment: How about trying `.factory("testFactory", ["$location", "$http", $rootScope", function($location, $http, $rootScope) { ... }]);`

Comment: Make sure that you are doing `$rootScope.test = 123;` before you do `testFactory.testFunction();`

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm running through the exact same problem. In the console I can see the attribute in the first console.log but in the second when trying to print the attribute itself it comes as undefined

Comment: I ended up using $dispatch on the $rootScope to notify the factory function when the value was set, which is shown in an example here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw .  This might not be the most elegant solution, but worked for my scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.test = 123;
}]);

myApp.controller('AppController', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.test);
}]);
```

**Plunker:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/7NTGOK

I guess that you are *reading* the value before you are *writing* it.

**UPDATE**

The debugging experience is really weird here. However, in my updated plunker you can see through the timestamps that the writing happens after reading:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pn5Wxk

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't post a picture, but in my Chrome console, when I print out console.log($rootScope) first and expand the object, I see "test: 123" defined.  After that line I print console.log($rootscope.test) and it shows up as undefined.  How could I see the value in the log with $rootScope, but not as $rootScope.test?

Comment: Sounds strange indeed but there's always a reason :) Can you try to put together a small test case in a plunkr? Or do you have your app accessible somewhere online?

Comment: I've edited the original question and added the plunker link.

Comment: The debugging experience is really weird here. However, in my updated plunker you can see through the timestamps that the writing happens after reading: http://plnkr.co/edit/pn5Wxk

Comment: Thanks for the help Christoph!  Timing is the issue (as it often with angular).  I am trying to read before the write is complete.  The confusion lies with Chrome displaying weird results in the console.  To resolve my timing problem, I finally added a $rootScope.$dispatch(...) line and listen for the event in another controller as explained here -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw